# regarding matrix comparison in R

Tags: r

Currently, I have two matrixes, and want to compare it and see whether they are exactly equivalent. In R, is there any function to do that?

Comment: `?all.equal` or `all(m1==m2)`

Comment: `?identical` may also be an option

Comment: sel <- source_df[, ] == target_df[, ] # gives you dataframe with TRUE and FALSE values

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As stated above start with `?all.equal` or `?identical`. If you then find that your matrices are unequal, you may want to compare them column by column. This might do the trick:

`mapply(as.data.frame(m1),as.data.frame(m2),FUN=function(v1,v2) all(v1==v2) )`